# Gatsby-image is displaying greater than the set maxWidth property

Tags: gatsby

I have a gatsby page which has 2 columns of equal width, a header on top, and a footer at the bottom.  I have some content in the left column and an image in the right column.  I am using graphql to query an fluid image.  I set the maxWidth property but when the page loads, the image is still of original size, roughly 700 x 800.  Any help in what is causing this would be greatly appreciated as i am still new to gatsby.  Thank you.

```
const About = (props) => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Row className={aboutStyles.padding}>
        <Col>
          <h1 className="text-center">Test Page</h1>
          <div>
            <p>This is the left column</p>
          </div>
        </Col>
        <Col>
          <Img fluid={props.data.dumpTruck.childImageSharp.fluid} />
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default About

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query {
    dumpTruck: file(relativePath: { eq: "dumpTruck.jpg" }) {
      childImageSharp {
        fluid(maxWidth: 400) {
          ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Comment: Do you need more help with this question?

Comment: I have moved on from Gatsby/GraphQL as I wasn't able to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Check the docs for [Avoiding stretched images using the fluid type](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-image/#avoiding-stretched-images-using-the-fluid-type)

> images using the fluid type are stretched to match the container’s width. In the case where the image’s width is smaller than the available viewport, the image will stretch to match the container, potentially leading to unwanted problems and worsened image quality.
>
> To counter this edge case one could wrap the Img component in order to set a better, for that case, maxWidth:

```
const NonStretchedImage = props => {
  let normalizedProps = props
  if (props.fluid && props.fluid.presentationWidth) {
    normalizedProps = {
      ...props,
      style: {
        ...(props.style || {}),
        maxWidth: props.fluid.presentationWidth,
        margin: "0 auto", // Used to center the image
      },
    }
  }

  return <Img {...normalizedProps} />
}
```

> Note: The GatsbyImageSharpFluid fragment does not include presentationWidth. You will need to add it in your graphql query as is shown in the following snippet:

```
{
  childImageSharp {
    fluid(maxWidth: 500, quality: 100) {
      ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
      presentationWidth
    }
  }
}
```